# Doubts on the proof regarding uniform convergence on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show $f_n'\rightrightarrows f'$ on the region $\Omega$.

Let $\Omega_\delta = \{z\in\Omega:\overline{D_\delta}(z)\subset \Omega\}$. The textbook I'm reading states that it suffices to show $f_n'\rightrightarrows f'$ on $\Omega_\delta$ for all $\delta$. It looks fine at first sight, but I don't know how it actually makes sense. Can somebody help?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $f$ and $f_n$? What does $f_n'\rightrightarrows f'$ mean? Do you mean “uniform convergence” or “locally uniform convergence”?

Comment: Oh, it is uniform convergence on every compact subset of $\Omega$.The assumption is that $f_n$ is holomorphic, which automatically implies that $f$ is holomorphic as well.

Comment: If $K \subset \Omega$ is compact then $K \subset \Omega_\delta$ for sufficiently small $\delta$.

Comment: I think I stated it imprecisely. We know that $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$ on very compact subset of $\Omega$. We originally wanted to prove that $f'_n$ uniformly converges to $f'$ on every compact subset of $\Omega$. But it suffices to show $f'_n$ uniformly converges to $f'$ on the whole region $\Omega$. How does your statement prove this claim?

Comment: That makes no sense. You cannot prove that $f_n' \to f'$ uniformly on the whole region $\Omega$. What you perhaps mean is that  $f_n' \to f'$ uniformly on every $\Omega_\delta$, and that implies $ f_n' \to f'$ on every compact subset $K \subset \Omega$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.... Thanks